# How to put the logo text to the left corner using flexbox in this case?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here I am trying to keep the navigation buttons in the center of the navbar using flexbox. But whenever I try to center using the justify-content property using flexbox the logo text also moves along the navigation buttons. I want the logo text on the left corner and buttons on the center. Any fix for this using flexbox?

```css
/* -----------
   1. global-setup
   ----------- */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*  -----------
   2. navigation-container
   ----------- */

.nav {
    background-color: #BA8C63;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav .logo {
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.nav .logo p {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
    padding-left: 40px;

}

div.li ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e6cbb3;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #e6cbb3;
    color: #BA8C63;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flexbox Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oleo+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <p>Woody</p>
    </div>
    <div class="li">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* -----------
   1. global-setup
   ----------- */

   * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*  -----------
   2. navigation-container
   ----------- */

.nav {
    background-color: #BA8C63;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;

}

.nav .logo {
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
.li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;/*same code but aplys for only li class not whole nav*/
  width: 100%;/*fill available space*/
}
.nav .logo p {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
    padding-left: 40px;

}

div.li ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e6cbb3;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #e6cbb3;
    color: #BA8C63;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flexbox Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oleo+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <p>Woody</p>
    </div>
    <div class="li">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here we apply center only for .li class (not for whole nav) and make the .li to fit the remaining space other than logo

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* -----------
   1. global-setup
   ----------- */
  
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  
/*  -----------
   2. navigation-container
   ----------- */
  
.nav {
  background-color: #BA8C63;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
.nav::after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}
  
.nav .logo {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
  
.nav .logo p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
  padding-left: 40px;
  
}
  
div.li ul {
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
  
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6cbb3;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
}
  
a:hover {
  background-color: #e6cbb3;
  color: #BA8C63;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flexbox Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oleo+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <p>Woody</p>
    </div>
    <div class="li">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```